# How to integrate 2 android apps

Tags: android, android-studio, integration

I want to integrate 2 android apps which are developed in android studio and these are open source apps and i have the source code available.

For example, I have App1 and App2,  I want to integrate App2 inside App1. so that there would be a single AndroidManifest.xml file (of App1) and a single apk would be generated.

I want to know the best way to go about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those two Apps communicate between them or their Activities are completly displayed for their own features without interoperate with the other App? If the answer is "them are completly separated Activities" then the fastest solution is "a simple copy/paste" files from App2 to App1 ;)

Comment: @emandt Thank you. Btw the 2 apps share data between them

Comment: So most of the work remain "copy & paste" files/classes/resources and then you need to let those common parts cooperate without conflicts...

Comment: ok thanks @emandt ill try it.